# Export data from SharePoint to Tableau with python

Tags: python, sharepoint, tableau-api

Is there a way to extract data from share point excel data and push through to tableau?

I have connecting from tableau, but I feel python might be the best option. Just not sure on the function to use

Comment: Depending on what version of SharePoint you are running and which version of Excel you have; you should be able to export any list in SharePoint directly to Excel.  SharePoint has been a part of MS Office since it began so there has always been a natural integration